# Validate multiline text so that all lines contain text with a strict, pipe-delimited format

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, multiline

Let's say we have an input that may consist of one or more lines of text and all lines must obey a strict format.

```
number|any character(s)|number
```

Ex.:

```
150|example.com/|2500
600|hello_world|1500
```

The characters in the middle may contain any characters, excluding whitespace. The numbers in the beginning and the end may consist of a single or multiple digits.

I want to check that all lines in the text obey the required format.

So far I came up with the following regex, but it's returning `true` even if only one line matches the format from above.

```
/[0-9]+\|.*?\|[0-9]/im
```

How can I adjust my pattern to validate the whole text and return `true` from `preg_match()`?

Comment: Number can be ```\d``` for a single digit number or ```\d+``` for any number of digits.

Comment: @mickmackusa The characters in the middle may contain any characters, excluding whitespace. The numbers in the beginning and the end may consist of a single or multiple digits. Here are some other samples: 150|https://google.com/|2500
600|hello_world|1500

Comment: I updated the answer below to reflect the "no whitespace in the middle" requirement.

Comment: Are you sure any non-space characters are allowed in the middle part including the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/\A([0-9]+\|\S*\|[0-9]+)(?:\R(?1))*\z/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rdKxsV/3). *Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `([0-9]+\|\S*\|[0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits, `|`, any zero or more nonwhitespace chars, as many as possible, `|`, and one or  more digits
- `(?:\R(?1))*` - zero or more repetitions of a line break and then Group 1 pattern
- `\z` - end of string.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/shdNe):

```php
$text = "150|google.com/|2500\n600|hello_world|1500";
if (preg_match('~\A([0-9]+\|\S*\|[0-9]+)(?:\R(?1))*\z~', $text)){
    echo "Valid!";
}
// => Valid!
```